# How would I use my domain on my windows server 2012?

Tags: iis, dns, server, cross-domain, windows-server-2008

I recently started a project of building a server at home and trying to host a website on it. I have almost everything setup and working correctly but only have one issue, I can't figure out how to use my domain with it. I've been searching the internet for a few days and everything I come across isn't very informative on how to do it. I'm very new to hosting my own servers and would love any help. Thanks in advanced.

I should also mention that I'm using `Windows Server 2012 R2` and `IIS 8`. The computer has a static IP as well.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by use my domain but I am guessing if you go to the url it is not loading you site? If that is the case, have you registered you bomain with a provider (godaddy, namecheep, etc)? After that make sure your router is forwarding the ports needed to your computer. Lastly make sure that those ports are open on your firewall. Things to help debug issues is can you ping your domain and get your static IP, if not the issue is with your domain registration. If it tries to load the site and doesn't but the IP is good then the issue is between the provider and you computer more than likely.

Comment: I want it to act as a web server. When someone visits my domain in the browser I want it to load the website from IIS. I don't know how to do this though. I own the domain as well.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/323972 that might be of some use. IIS uses port 80 for HTTP and 443 for HTTPS. Also in the browser you should be able to go to localhost and view the site to see if iis is even loading it.